# Convince an IT department to keep using Ruby on Rails instead of Kohana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kohana

I have to give a 30 minute presentation on why our IT Dept should keep using Ruby on Rails, instead of using the Kohana framework (which is for PHP).

I have 3 years of solid success from past Ruby on Rails apps, but the whole "Everyone knows PHP" argument seems to be more important than anything else.

I am not the greatest speaker and I don't really have time to make a presentation anyway.

Are there any decent presentation slides or other presentation-worthy materials that can help me convince the IT Dept to keep using Rails?

Comment: Try looking here: http://www.quora.com/What-advantages-does-Ruby-programming-language-have-over-PHP-OOP-for-web-applications

Answer (score 9):

**This is far less about language vs language and more about influencing people.**  Whaat?

If there is one theme I observe with "this language" vs "that language" is that they go round and round forever.  Yes you'll find lots of material out there, including the [quora.com](http://www.quora.com/What-advantages-does-Ruby-programming-language-have-over-PHP-OOP-for-web-applications) link that @thisfeller posted.  Check this out - apparently [COBOL is still the 'queen'](http://nerds-central.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/cobol-vs-java-for-financial.html) (whatever that means).  What is more likely to swing it your way is understanding how to influence people (towards your viewpoint).

If the IT dept are pushing for a change in language/framework there will usually be one or two reasons behind that.  **Understanding those reasons** (is it really just 'everyone knows php'?) will be crucial to you being able to defend continuing the use of Rails.  Understand those reasons and then explain why it'll still be ok (preferably better) by sticking to Rails.

**Of course I'm assuming** that you're right about Rails being better for your organisation.  I cannot comment on that.  Look back on the past Rails projects and **highlight the successes**, especially where perhaps you've used a gem to get some feature or functionality down in a matter of hours rather than days or weeks.

Consider what the integration and migration would look like when you shift over from Rails to Kohana.  Actually it'll probably be smoother than the other way around but hey.  Try to understand personally how making the move is beneficial.  If you cannot convince yourself that it's the right thing to do, then use that conviction as a basis for your presentation.  If you take someone elses Ruby vs PHP or Rails vs Kohana presentation **it's likely that it won't hit on the relevant points for your organisation**.

Make sure that your presentation has content that is **aimed at your audience**.  If they are all developers then fine, get into all the technical detail you like.  If they are management types that don't have a technical background, don't get all jargonny on them.  They'll think '*who is this guy*' and '*lets not do what he says - I don't get any of it*'.

**Most importantly**, identify who the key decision-makers are.  Then identify who the key influencers are on those decision-makers.  Then go out and talk to them.  Understand their viewpoint, if they have one.  Look for people that support your viewpoint and involve them.  Get them to talk to the influencers and decision-makers.  What you absolutely want to avoid is the situation where the first time these decision makers and influencers hear about '*why we should keep Rails*' is during your presentation.  You must approach them beforehand and get them familiar to your viewpoint.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for the IT department one point is that with Rails you'll have developers that know Ruby, and Ruby has a ton of uses outside of the Rails framework. php people will probably know phython but its not a given.

However if you need to prove something I would do a demo. Afterall let the languages speak for themselves.

Take someone who doesn't know either and maybe do the 15 minute blog exercise with them, in both Rails and php. I would think the thing speaks for itself. I knew the second I started using Ruby it was better (in my eyes) than php. That's not to say that php is bad per se.

Also the community is a strength that the Rails and Ruby projects have going for them too IMO. Generally we have nice ppl willing to help and the documentation is pretty good now. The codebase is well maintained and has a good track record of responding.

Good luck!